# Instantiate a class once per parameter in JUnit

Tags: junit, parameterized

So I'm trying to run tests that will evaluate certain properties of different websites. The actual evaluation is being handled by a pay-per-call resource, so I want to minimize the number of times I generate the resource. Also, I need this to run in JUnit to fit into a larger automated test suite.

I've been doing this with parameterized tests so far, but I just learned that they instantiate a new instance for each test method.

Now I'm trying to figure out a way to have the resource created just once for each parameter that is being fed into the constructor of my testing class. @BeforeClass does it just once, and @Before does it once before each test.

All the help topics I've been able to find have dealt with creating expensive resources once for all tests, but in this case I need the resource to be recreated for each new set of parameters.

I've written some example code / output below to better show what I'm looking for:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTestClass {

    private static Resource expensiveToCreateResource;

    public MyTestClass(String url) {
        System.out.println("Constructing resource for " + url);
        expensiveToCreateResource = new Resource(url); //This is getting created 4x, which is wrong
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{"url1"},{"url2"}});
    }

    @Test
    public test1() {
        expensiveToCreateResource.method1();
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test 
    public test2() {
        expensiveToCreateResource.method2();
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

would produce output:

```
Constructing resource for url1
test1
test2
Constructing resource for url2
test1
test2
```

Any ideas / solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the class instantiated once per parameter, you'll have to write your own JUnit test runner. Instead I'd try to cache the information as needed, e.g. in a static map that maps URLs to resources.